# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2

Tags: flutter, dart

In this app I am trying to get the query based on the 'listen' event. If there is any change in the database the data in the mobile screen will change.
Below is the code to get the data from the DB.

```
  quizStart(){
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('quizes').doc(docId).get().then((value) {
      length = value.data()['questions'].length;
    });

    ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('quizes').doc(docId).collection('sessions').doc(recId).snapshots().listen((event) {
      var op = event.data();
      print('getData: $length');
      if(length == op['session']['index']){
        print('length: $length op: ${op['session']['index']}');
        showExitDialog('You have Completed the Quizi...');
      }else
      if(op['session']['active'] == false)
        showExitDialog('The Quizi has been ended..');
      else
       if(op['session']['createdAt'] == null )
        showDialog();
      else {
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => AnswersPage(
                    docId: docId, recId: recId, playerName: playerName)));
      
      }
    });
  }
```

I am displaying the data using the Gridview builder.

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: sessionQuery,
                builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){
                  if(snapshot.hasError)
                    return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState){
                    case ConnectionState.waiting: return Text('Loading ...');
                    default: queIndex = snapshot.data['session']['index'];
                    return StreamBuilder(
                      stream: questionTypeQuery,
                        builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snap){
                          if(snap == null && snap.hasError)
                            return Text('Error: ${snap.error}');
                          switch (snap.connectionState){
                            case ConnectionState.waiting: return Text('Quizi! is Loading ... Please Wait');
                            default:
                           answerType = snap.data['questions'][queIndex]['answertype'].toString();
                              points = snap.data['questions'][queIndex]['points'].toString();
                              question =snap.data['questions'][queIndex]['question'].toString();
                              quesLength = snap.data['questions'][queIndex]['answers'].length;
                                return RubberBand(
                                  key: gridAnim,
                                  child: GridView.builder(
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount:2),
                                    itemCount: quesLength,
                                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                                      return InkWell(
                                          onTap: (){
                                         showDialog('Look Out for the next question...');
                                          },

                                          child: Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                              child: Material(
                                                elevation: 5,
                                                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                                child: Container(
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    boxShadow: [
                                                      BoxShadow(
                                                        color: Colors.yellowAccent.withOpacity(0.5),
                                                        offset: const Offset(1.0, 1.0,), blurRadius: 5.0, spreadRadius: 0.5,),
                                                      BoxShadow(color: Colors.white,
                                                        offset: const Offset(0.0, 0.0), blurRadius: 0.0, spreadRadius: 0.0,), ],
                                                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent, width: 2.0, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                                                    color: Colors.deepPurple[500], borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                                  ),
                                               child: Center(child:
                                                  Text(snap.data['questions'][queIndex]['answers'][index]['answer'].toString(),
                                                      style: GoogleFonts.bubblegumSans(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25,))),
                                                ),
                                              )

                                          ));
                                    },
                                  ),
                                );
                          }
                  });
                }}
              ),
```

I am getting errors in the 9th line of the above code.

Even though the condition which is working in the quizStart() I am getting the range error.

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Thanks for the response @PareshMangukiya. I am using nested Streambuilder and then I am returning GridView.builder and the itemcount in this is working fine. If you check the code i am using a streambuilder returning another streambuilder and then returning the GridView builder. the issue is with the first streambuilder.
can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used to display the second Streambuilder.

(ex)

```
If(condition)
 return Widget
else
 return StreamBuilder.
```

Now I am getting the required output.

I don't know this is the correct solution for this error. But this worked for me.

Thanks.